# Create Grid Layout on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, grid, portfolio

I'm wondering if anyone could answer this question for me, the solution at the bottom didn't work for my situation.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-a-page-with-a-2-or-3-column-content-layout

I'm working on a blank canvas at the minute. Haven't got a design for the page yet as the rest of the page's appearance will depend on whether or not I can get this element working.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated. Can't get my head around how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a grid page layout for portfolio using wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343828/creating-a-grid-page-layout-for-portfolio-using-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

just put your posts into divs for now

```
<?php if (have_posts()) ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<div class="wppost">
<h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p>">Read more...
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and then style .wppost (or whatever you name it)
like so .wppost{width:32%; float:left}

that's not perfect, but it'll get you started. check out jQuery Masonry for an easy, slick fx for that.